# R: Parse a string by 3 consecutive letters

Tags: r, regex, stringr, text-parsing

I have item codes and descriptions in the same column.
The item codes can have letters, numbers, spaces and special characters.
The description always starts with at least 4 letters.
So I wanted to split the column at the space where the 4 letters begin.
I converted the text field to lowercase

```
x <- c('1234 (a)-b free vacation to aruba',
       '1234:43-1b free set of dishes')
```

Ideally this would yield:

```
itemCode         itemDesctiption
1234 (a)-b       free vacation to aruba
1234:43-1b       free set of dishes
```

I tried splitting by spaces

```
[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')] <- str_split_fixed(x, ' ', 6)
```

but of course since spaces are sometimes embedded, it doesn't give me what I want.

I reviewed similar question, which are close, but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(x, "^.+(?=\\s[:alpha:]{4,}\\s)")` will extract to `"1234 (a)-b free" "1234:43-1b" ` but it's going to be difficult to parse things such as the first entry that have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this in base R using `strsplit` with a lookahead to get the item code, then to get the description remove the item code from the original string using `sub`:

```r
x <- c('1234 (a)-b free vacation to aruba',
       '1234:43-1b free set of dishes')

a <- sapply(strsplit(x, '(?=[a-z]{4})', perl = TRUE), function(x) x[1])
b <- unlist(Map(function(a, b) sub(a, "", b, fixed = TRUE), a, x))

data.frame(itemCode = a, itemDescription = b, row.names = NULL)
#>      itemCode        itemDescription
#> 1 1234 (a)-b  free vacation to aruba
#> 2 1234:43-1b      free set of dishes
```

There's a slight caveat that `[a-z]{4}` will only work if the first 4 letters don't contain letters outside the standard 26 symbols in this set (for example, accented letters).

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `[a-z]{4}` will only match 4 letter matches- the question states "at least four letters" so maybe it should be `[a-z]{4,}`.

Comment: @JustinCocco logically, if you want to find the first location where there are 4 or more characters, then this is the same as finding the first location with four characters. Or do I misunderstand you? Could you give a counterexample where it would make a difference?

Comment: @AllanCameron Hey Allan -- that is correct -- when I see 4 or more characters in a row, I want to split that into a separate column, beginning with the first character in that 4 or more character string.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on `tidyr`'s function `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(x) %>%
  extract(x,
          into = c("itemCode", "itemDescription"),
          regex = "([()0-9a-z-]+)[\\s-]+([a-z]{4,}\\s.*)"
  )
            itemCode                                                   itemDescription
1           04(4)(a)                                          vacation - 2-3 weeks obo
2         230(11)(a)                                          cars - - 18 plus winners
3                073                                                boxes of choclates
4         130(11)(a)                   wont be offering -- too expensive - see details
5      23-3057(a)(5)                     grand prize / cruise for >= 18 year old (min)
6             33-314                                      choice of prizes & $500 cash
7  656-2-316(a)(iii) free books < 100 / price < 13 & 27 dollars. / or choice of prizes
8           231-5510                                           airfare (more than 200)
9           5er20c1a                                               prizes (under $500)
10             520g2                                                   prizes over 500
11         35-42-4-9                                                   prizes 250 plus
12        130(11)(b)                                                  retired category
```

How the `regex` works: essentially, the strings in `x` are divided into two capture groups containing what is to be extracted into the two new columns:

- `(.*[()0-9abc-])`: the 1st capture group; here we assert that the group ends on any of parenthesis, digits, dash, or `a`, `b`, or `c` (please adapt as you see fit!)
- `\\s`: one whitespace (not captured)
- `([a-z]{4,}\\s.*)`: 2nd capture group. here we assert that there must be at least 4 lower-case letters followed by one whitespace and more characters

**EDIT 1**:

check out:

`regex = "([()0-9a-z-]+)[\\s-]+(.*)"`

seems to work too!

**EDIT 2**:

based on the observation that `itemCode` is never interrupted by whitespace, this works too:

`regex = "(\\S+)[\\s-]+(.*)"`

Comment: Hey folks -- thanks for the input.  My apologies for not including more rows -- I am new to pattern recognition so sorry for any inconvenience .

Comment: x <- c(
"800.04(4)(a) - vacation - 2-3 weeks obo",
"9a.44.230(11)(a) - cars  - - 18 plus winners",
"9a.434.073 - boxes of choclates",
"9a.444.130(11)(a) - wont be  offering -- too expensive - see details",
"23-3057(a)(5) - grand prize / cruise for >= 18 year old (min)",
"33-314 - choice of prizes & $500 cash",
"656-2-316(a)(iii) - free books < 100 / price < 13 & 27 dollars.  / or choice of prizes",
"231-5510 - airfare (more than 200)",
"750.5er20c1a - prizes (under $500)",
"s750.520g2 - prizes over 500",
"35-42-4-9 - prizes 250 plus",
"9a.4344.130(11)(b) - retired category"

)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code with `str_extract`

```r
data.frame(x=c('1234 (a)-b free vacation to aruba',
       '1234:43-1b free set of dishes')) %>% 
mutate(itemCode=str_extract_all(trimws(x), '\\d+.*[\\-|\\d]\\w\\s(?=\\w{4})'),
itemDesctiption=str_extract_all(trimws(x), '\\s\\w{4}\\s.*'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
                                  x    itemCode         itemDesctiption
1 1234 (a)-b free vacation to aruba  1234 (a)-b   free vacation to aruba
2     1234:43-1b free set of dishes  1234:43-1b       free set of dishes
```

Comment: thanks -- and sorry -- but it doesn't work with the newer data I posted on Jan 21.